# SCCM 2012 unable to update boot images with pxe enabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, configuration, pxe-boot, sccm

we are fighting an error in sccm 2012.  When we attempt to distribute boot images (after selecting the pxe option) we receive an error that the pxe image cannot be expanded (distmgr log).

Can you give us any direction on what to try or attempt in this scenario?  We only have one dp in our environment at the moment, however we have found that by creating another dp on a different server we don’t have this problem.  However we really need the primary site to be a dp.

We have tried:
Removing and reinstalling the dp
Removing and reinstalling the WDS
Reinstalled the OS ... ouch
Reinstalled SQL
Reinstalled SCCM 2012
We even attempted to manually mount these wims in the remote install folder, no luck...

And we have been working on this for days...

Any and all help is appreciated!

Our log is below

```
Attempting to add or update a package on a distribution point.  SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM         6924 (0x1B0C)
The distribution point is on the siteserver and the package is a content type package. There is nothing to be copied over.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
STATMSG: ID=2342 SEV=I LEV=M SOURCE="SMS Server" COMP="SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER" SYS=OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us SITE=IVC PID=3600 TID=6924 GMTDATE=Fri Jun 22 19:49:41.559 2012 ISTR0="Boot image (x86)" ISTR1="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\" ISTR2="" ISTR3="" ISTR4="" ISTR5="" ISTR6="" ISTR7="" ISTR8="" ISTR9="" NUMATTRS=2 AID0=400 AVAL0="IVC00001" AID1=404 AVAL1="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
The current user context will be used for connecting to ["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
No network connection is needed to ["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\ as this is the local machine.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Signature share exists on distribution point path \\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\SMSSIG$                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Ignoring drive C:\.  File C:\NO_SMS_ON_DRIVE.SMS exists.         SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM         6924 (0x1B0C)
user(NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) runing application(SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER) from machine (OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us) is submitting SDK changes from site(IVC)               SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM          6924 (0x1B0C)
Share SMSPKGD$ exists on distribution point \\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\SMSPKGD$                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Creating, reading and or updating Operations Management server role registry keys for a Distribution Point ...                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
user(NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) runing application(SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER) from machine (OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us) is submitting SDK changes from site(IVC)               SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM          6924 (0x1B0C)
Creating, reading or updating IIS registry key for a distribution point.       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM          6924 (0x1B0C)
IISPortsList in the SCF is "80".      SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISSSLPortsList in the SCF is "443".             SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISWebSiteName in the SCF is "".              SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISSSLState in the SCF is 224.       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:41 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Virtual Directory SMS_DP_SMSPKG$ for the physical path F:\SCCMContentLib already exists.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
STATMSG: ID=2375 SEV=I LEV=M SOURCE="SMS Server" COMP="SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER" SYS=OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us SITE=IVC PID=3600 TID=6924 GMTDATE=Fri Jun 22 19:49:42.058 2012 ISTR0="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\" ISTR1="" ISTR2="" ISTR3="" ISTR4="" ISTR5="" ISTR6="" ISTR7="" ISTR8="" ISTR9="" NUMATTRS=1 AID0=404 AVAL0="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Creating, reading or updating IIS registry key for a distribution point.       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM          6924 (0x1B0C)
IISPortsList in the SCF is "80".      SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISSSLPortsList in the SCF is "443".             SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISWebSiteName in the SCF is "".              SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
IISSSLState in the SCF is 224.       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Virtual Directory SMS_DP_SMSSIG$ for the physical path D:\SMSSIG$ already exists.      SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER                6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
STATMSG: ID=2375 SEV=I LEV=M SOURCE="SMS Server" COMP="SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER" SYS=OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us SITE=IVC PID=3600 TID=6924 GMTDATE=Fri Jun 22 19:49:42.105 2012 ISTR0="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\" ISTR1="" ISTR2="" ISTR3="" ISTR4="" ISTR5="" ISTR6="" ISTR7="" ISTR8="" ISTR9="" NUMATTRS=1 AID0=404 AVAL0="["Display=\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"]MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\"                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
user(NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) runing application(SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER) from machine (OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us) is submitting SDK changes from site(IVC)               SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM          6924 (0x1B0C)
RDC:Successfully created package signature file from \\?\F:\SMSPKGSIG\IVC00001.3 to \\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\SMSSIG$\IVC00001.3.tar                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Setting permissions on file MSWNET:["SMS_SITE=IVC"]\\OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us\SMSSIG$\IVC00001.3.tar.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
ExpandPXEImage: IVC00001, 1024            SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
CContentDefinition::GetFileProperties failed; 0x80070003            SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM         6924 (0x1B0C)
CContentDefinition::TotalFileSizes failed; 0x80070003     SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
**ExpandPXEImage failed; 0x80070003       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012** 2:49:42 PM    6924 (0x1B0C)
Error occurred. Performing error cleanup prior to returning.        SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM         6924 (0x1B0C)
DP thread with array index 0 ended.       SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
DP thread with thread handle 00000000000013A4 and thread ID 6924 ended.      SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER                6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
Updating package info for package IVC00001      SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
Package IVC00001 does not have a preferred sender.     SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
The package and/or program properties for package IVC00001 have not changed,  need to determine which site(s) need updated package info.   SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
StoredPkgVersion (3) of package IVC00001. StoredPkgVersion in database is 3.  SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER                6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
SourceVersion (3) of package IVC00001. SourceVersion in database is 3.                SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER                6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
STATMSG: ID=2302 SEV=E LEV=M SOURCE="SMS Server" COMP="SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER" SYS=OURSERVER.ourdomain.cc.ia.us SITE=IVC PID=3600 TID=4492 GMTDATE=Fri Jun 22 19:49:42.292 2012 ISTR0="Boot image (x86)" ISTR1="IVC00001" ISTR2="" ISTR3="" ISTR4="" ISTR5="" ISTR6="" ISTR7="" ISTR8="" ISTR9="" NUMATTRS=1 AID0=400 AVAL0="IVC00001"         SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
**Failed to process package IVC00001 after 0 retries, will retry 100 more times**        SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER                6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
Exiting package processing thread.          SMS_DISTRIBUTION_MANAGER              6/22/2012 2:49:42 PM    4492 (0x118C)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use UNC paths, even when the source is on the local server. Oh, and don't use the local server for data source, it just takes up space. And make sure the unc file path is not too long. When distributing boot images sccm creates an on-the-fly mount of the wim, whihch has a very long, random filename, in the source directory. if you are accessing a local drive you may have a read/write problem. UNC paths are easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very same issue. The PXE image would not expand. I tried a few things you mentioned (removing/reinstalling DP, WDS, etc) with the exception of the OS. I had gone to far along to go back. The solution ended up having to create a new DP on a new server. Since I have done this SCCM has worked like a charm. We are 100% virtual so putting up a new server was quick and may not be an option for you. In addition, to be clear we moved WDS/PXE to the new DP as well.